# Validating if a user exists in 2 tables in Active Record (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models: Proposal and Customer.
Proposal and Customer have an attr: "customer_id" and "updated_at" (default in rails).

Proposal **belongs_to: customer**

I need to validate if exists a proposal for a customer and if this proposal was created yesterday.

I tried some approaches but without success.

I tried to use the code:

```
Proposal.joins(:customer).where(customer: {customer_id: proposal: customer_id}, proposal.created_at = '2020-10-06 14:22:31'})
```

and

```
Proposal.joins("INNER JOIN customer ON Customer.customer_id = Proposal.customer_id AND Proposal.updated_at = '2020-10-06 14:22:31'")
```

Obs: I used **2020-10-06 14:22:31** because I have some data in my models where update_at is **'2020-10-06 14:22:31'** so, I used it only to show if my query is true.

Tried other approaches but with no success.

How can I to make this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that complicated. You could query like this:

```rb
date = Date.parse('2020-10-06')

Proposal.where(customer_id: customer_id, created_at: date.all_day)
```

Comment: But if the date was one day ago, if I to use ```1.day.ago``` will be correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, as `1.day.ago` retruns a date of yesterday.